# next.js - env vs serverRuntimeConfig

Tags: environment-variables, next.js

I read about `serverRuntimeConfig` here: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/runtime-configuration

Now my `next.config.js` is:

```
module.exports = withCSS({
  target: 'serverless',
  reactStrictMode: false,
  env: {
     SECRET: 'SECRET'
  }
});
```

I'm wondering, should I use `serverRuntimeConfig` for my secret env var instead of `env` ?
What are the pros / cons ?

Answer (score 3):

```
Generally you'll want to use build-time environment variables to provide your configuration. The reason for this is that runtime configuration adds rendering / initialization overhead and is incompatible with Automatic Static Optimization.

# https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/runtime-configuration
```

As they said, the runtime configuration in `next.config.js` may cause overhead.

So I suggest using `env` in `next.config.js`, or using the `.env*` files in this new method (https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables)

The code using your secret env vars should be in the server-side (API routes, getStaticProps, getServerSideProps), not in client-side (components...). If you reference them in client-side, they may be exposed!

Comment: But I use this env vars only in server side code, so how they may be exposed? I don't understand. If I'm getting you right, although runtime vars have some overhead, I should use them in order to make sure secret vars will not be send to the browser.

Comment: Maybe you misunderstand me. What I mean is if you provide the env vars values before `next build`, they may be expose in the bundle and sent to the browser. What I advise you is to provide env vars values when running your app `next start`. And you know that your code use the env in server side, so don't worry, they won't be exposed. Another way is use .env files supported by latest version of Next.js. They guide us: if we want to expose the env var to browser, please add a prefix in your env var like NEXT_PUBLIC_env_name, other env var without that prefix, they would not be exposed

Comment: So just to make sure, what I did (use `env` in `next.config.js`) is ok right?

Comment: It's okay but you have to understand how env values is put in env when your app build & run. So I request you to dump the value of your secret env var in your browser to see if it's leaked or not, if it's not so it's okay!

Comment: But it is clear that if I will write in client side code something like `console.log(process.env.SECRET)` it will be exposed and printed to the console, because the secret will be replaced in build time (?). But if I am using `process.env.SECRET` only on the server side code (and don't send it to the client) it will not be exposed. So we can say it is not a must to use `serverRuntimeConfig` but it can save us from accidently expose secrets to the client. am I getting it right?

Comment: How you `don't send it to the client`? You said you use the env on server side code, but are you sure that it cannot be used on client side code? As I said above, you may send/leak to the client if you provide your env from build time. My advice is **not** providing any env when build (next build), only provide when run (next start). And the `console.log(process.env.SECRET)` is a double check, you can provide random value and print to see the output, just for security testing, if it's safe (the secret value is null or not printed), then remove the `console.log`

Comment: Along with my above answer, I recommend you trying 2 ways below to understand the behavior:
1. Have `console.log(process.env.SECRET)` in your server side & client side code. Provide process.env.SECRET, run `next build`, then `next start` and check the output in server side & client side.
2. Have `console.log(process.env.SECRET)` in your server side & client side code. Do not provide process.env.SECRET, run `next build`, then `next start` and check the output in server side & client side.

Comment: "How you don't send it to the client?", I'm using those env vars only in `/api` folder code. I'm building a serverless app. next.js doc says its a server side code and not send into the client. I'm not sure why you are suggesting those tests, it is clear that if I will put `console.log(process.env.SECRET)` in client side code, it will print the secret value. I think that `serverRuntimeConfig` just helping the programmer not to expose secrets accidently.

Comment: Could you give me the link for clarifying the `I'm building a serverless app. next.js doc says its a server side code and not send into the client`? And I didn't know that you are using serverless target!

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction. "They are server-side only bundles and won't increase your client-side bundle size."

Comment: They didn't mention about whether env is sent to client or not? The code in client/server side is a different one with the env. Please double check for security reason

Comment: the env vars are environment variables so if you will mention them in client side code, they will be sent to the client. I don't know if their values are assigned at build time (`next build`) or at runtime (`next start`). but if i need to guess i would say runtime.

Comment: I've create a small serverless Next.js app to double check, it's safe to use `env` in next.config.js for secrets if we don't use `process.env.xyz` in client side (components..). I tried setting the env value and run build, they write the value into the html.

Comment: Thanks :) thats exactly what i thought